# After database corruption, errors are being produced

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2007

I had a split database working fine on a clients machine for over 2 years. Due to unknown circumstances the database became corrupted. And was fixed by the removal of a couple of corrupted records.

The front end has now began to produce the following errors:

```
2147352567

2448
```

These errors will be thrown individually when a user performs a certain action.

How can it be that these errors have suddenly started to show themselves up when before everything was working fine?

Without wanting to bog down this question with code, the premise of the forms when the error occurs are that:

> A form is open and an excel spreadsheet may also be open that relates
>   to that record.
>
> On save/close of the excel spreadsheet a corresponding field in the database record is updated.
>
> The user decides to 'Update Excel Spreadsheet' or 'Save and Close'
>
> The errors occur on Before_Update events on the access form

Is there any reason that these errors might have started occurring in what appeared to be a perfectly working system?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [Databases](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have always posted MS Access Questions in Stackoverflow.

Comment: but this IMO is not a programming related question which makes it off topic for Stack Overflow. This is general software related issue not a *code* related question.

Comment: @mehow no problem, hopefully it is an issue that relates to the software as opposed to the code.

Comment: Did some network structure change? I know that we've had issues with our DBs when our I.T. group migrated a virtual server to a non-mirrored configuration. This caused libraries to become unlinked/missing, among other miscellaneous issues.

Comment: The company upgraded their broadband and had a new router installed, may have caused the corruption? Maybe that would have effected the setup. Have tested the system on a VM and can replicate the errors.

Comment: Something easy to try would be to open a blank database, then import every object from the failing database. I have seen issues of 'strange behavior' with Access where I would spent far too much time trying to fix, but the import usually solved the problem. After a while, with certain 'unusual' errors, I just did the import and called it a day!

Comment: @Wayne, cheers I gave that a go, I'd say it helped overall but it never resolved the issue that I had. I have ended up changing the offending code to update the records (If me.dirty then me.dirty = False). Is applicable to do so and seems to work, so I am going to call it a day on this one!

Comment: @Noelmcg pick your battles / keep your powder dry / take the easy wins / [insert another proverb]. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by including in the code an appropriate update record:

> If Me.Dirty = True then
>   Me.Dirty = False
>   End if

Still don't understand how the errors began to arise though after the DB became corrupted?  The forms/buttons/actions would have been used daily by the users during their working week for over 2 years.

Comment: It has happened to me before, also. It really pisses me off because it happens randomly. For me, though, it was a report that would corrupt the whole Db when it was opened, only by an end user though. I had to delete and re-create the report; works without error.